# How do you set focus on the TO field of the MFMailComposeViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am using the standard boilerplate code for sending email with the MFMailComposeViewController, but I can find no information on setting focus on the TO field with the Plus button visible when the controller displays as it does for functions like "Mail Link to this Page" in Safari or "Share Location" in Maps.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer;              
mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailComposer setSubject:@"My Subject"];        
[mailComposer setMessageBody:@"This is the body of my message" isHTML:NO];      
[self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
[mailComposer release];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can peek inside the view of the mailComposer object:

```
UIView *v0 = mailComposer.view;
UIView *v1 = [[v0 subviews] objectAtIndex:0]; // UINavigationTransitionView
UIView *v2 = [[v1 subviews] objectAtIndex:0]; // UIViewControllerWrapperView
UIView *v3 = [[v2 subviews] objectAtIndex:0]; // MFMailComposeView
UIView *v4 = [[v3 subviews] objectAtIndex:0]; // UIView
UIView *v5 = [[v4 subviews] objectAtIndex:0]; // MFComposeScrollView
UIView *v6 = [[v5 subviews] objectAtIndex:0]; // UIView
UIView *v7 = [[v6 subviews] objectAtIndex:0]; // MFMailComposeRecipientView
UIView *v8 = [[v7 subviews] objectAtIndex:1]; // _MFMailRecipientTextField
```

This v8 guy is the one you want. It is a subclass of UITextField. Make it the first responder.

Officially, you should be checking the types of the subviews instead of taking the first or second object. But then again, officially you shouldn't be doing this at all, since this is all undocumented, and may break in future iOS versions.

Comment: Has this broken in iOS 7?